# JScrollPane doesn't seem to scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm pretty new to Java Swing. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Please correct me anywhere necessary. A good portion of this code was trial and error.

I have a frame, which contains a JPanel. The JPanel is using the "GridBag" layout. The code included revolves around the child JPanel on the right side as seen in the picture. For some reason, I can't seem get my vertical scrollbar working properly.

Here's the code of interest:

```
/// GridBagConstraints
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

// parent jpanel for scrollpane
scrollPanel = new JPanel();
scrollPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
add(scrollPanel, gbc);

// content jpanel for scrollpane
scrollPaneContent = new JPanel();
scrollPaneContent.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 1));

// scrollPane
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,30,0,0));
scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollPaneContent);
scrollPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

And here is what the program looks like at the moment.
You can see the numbers just go off the screen:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

You are attempting to add the scrollPane to the scrollPanel. That is not the way it works.

A `JScrollPane` is a container, so you need to add the panel containing the components to the scroll pane

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(...);
panel.add(....);
panel.add(....);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

The above code will add the panel to the "viewport" of the scroll pane.

Comment: I add the scrollPane to the scrollPanel, and I use scrollPaneContent as the viewport for the JScrollPane as seen here: scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollPaneContent);. Is this incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: @gab64, `Is this incorrect?` - I already told you it was incorrect and showed you the correct way to do it.

Comment: I see. I got it working the correct way now, thank you. As an alternative, I found that it also worked with:  setMinimumSize and setPreferredSize, however I was trying to avoid hardcoding the size. Thanks again!

Comment: @gab64, `As an alternative...` - no, that is not an alternative. Every component can have a different size on a different Look and Feel. Let the layout manager determine the preferred size dynamically. Any size you set will just be a random guess.